# Conditional Header in wordpress

Tags: php, functions, jquery, headers

I'm trying to modify the header in a theme for two specific custom post type.
The header for all theme page is output from this code:

```
<script>
        jQuery(function($){

        $('.parallax-window').parallax({imageSrc: '<?php echo  $ilgelo_options['ilgelo-parallax-image']['url'];?>'});
        });
</script>
```

I've tried to put my condional code:

```
<?php if ( is_singular( array( 'rivista', 'rivista-trimestrale' ) ) ) {
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){

        $('.parallax-window').parallax({imageSrc: '<?php echo  $ilgelo_options['ilgelo-parallax-image']['url'];?>'});
        });
    </script>
} else {

<script>
        jQuery(function($){

        $('.parallax-window').parallax({imageSrc: 'STYLESHEETPATH."/img/header-rivista.jpg"'});
        });
    </script>
    } 
?>
```

but I get a syntax error '<' and I can't understand why. 
Could someone help me please?
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, can you please add the exact error output to your question?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /homepages/18/d657484804/htdocs/clickandbuilds/DirittiComparati/wp-content/themes/journey-child/template/header/header-style4.php on line 17   *** Line 17 is where I have : <script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have forgotten to use `<?php` and `?>` properly. Remember to open and close the php tag like the following:

```
<?php if ( is_singular( array( 'rivista', 'rivista-trimestrale' ) ) ) {?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){

        $('.parallax-window').parallax({imageSrc: '<?php echo  $ilgelo_options['ilgelo-parallax-image']['url'];?>'});
        });
    </script><?php
} else { ?>

<script>
        jQuery(function($){

        $('.parallax-window').parallax({imageSrc: 'STYLESHEETPATH."/img/header-rivista.jpg"'});
        });
    </script><?php
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Tx a lot!!! it partially works: 'cause it sees the conditional output, evenif it doesn't take the link of the image: http://diritticomparati.themmc.it/rivista/test-articolo-rivista/

Comment: You're welcome. Can you more specific please? I can't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: Added screenshot belowe :)

Comment: There might be an issue with your conditional array, since it's outputting a value, but not the right one. Are you sure the names you entered in the array are correct? You might wanna double check that.

Comment: solved! I just put the full url to avoid mistakes :)

Comment: Good (tricky) catch, +1. @MonicaMariaCrapanzano: you could've easily avoided this error by using a good text editor, like SublimeText with PHP code checking enabled. or using an IDE.

Comment: @Fayaz, tx I'll try it :)